# Sumar la diferencia en cada multiplicacion usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

El problema es el siguiente estoy intentando hacer un programa que vaya multiplicando por 2 cada 2 veces. Pero que suma toda la diferencia de los numeros anteriores.

Por decirlo mas claramente, yo voy a seguir multiplicando por 2 cada 2 veces pero lo que necesito esque los numeros que haya multiplicado sumen todos los anteriores.

Ej.

```
1 2 2 4 4 8 8 16 16 32 32 64 64 128 128
```

Cuando los numeros van aumentando ejemplo el 8, resultado que la suma de los dos anteriores equivalen al siguiente pero como puedo hacer en mi programa para que sume los anteriores.

Entonces el programa lo que hace no es mas que multiplicar * 2 cada dos veces ej

```
if(i%2==0)
number = number * 2
```

Pero lo que quiero es que cada vez que multiplico *2  agregar la diferencia de los numeros que faltan para que la suma de todos los numeros anteriores sea la misma al siguiente?

Es simplemente lo que intento es alguna manera de hacer crecer mis numeros mas lentamente sin utilizar la multiplicacion.

Y disculpar por no explicarme tan bien en la logica matematica de mi programa ya que me cuesta a mi mismo dificultades para llevarlo a cabo.

Answer (score 0):

Tratando de enteder tu pregunta: Lo que pides es que cada dos veces se te duplique el numero que tienes a si mismo y en la primera vez solo sume los valores anteriores

(la duplicacion a si mismo es facil al crear una variable que contenga el valor anterior y se sume a si misma, se tiene una variable contador que lo ejecute cada dos veces)

(en cambio si sumas el numero anterior estarias haciendo un factorial lo cual no mostraria el resultado que estas esperando.

Entonces aqui te coloco un codigo que hace lo que estas pidiendo como resultado:

```js
     // ejecutar
        document.getElementById('ejecutar').addEventListener("click", function() {
            var veces = parseInt(document.getElementById('repetir').value); // numero de veces a multiplicar
            document.getElementById("numeros").innerHTML=""; // limpiar contenido
            var numero = 1;
            var conteo = 0;
            var valorAnterior = null; // valor anterior
            // ajuste para mostrar la secuencia de numeros; 
            repetir = veces + 2;
            if (veces%2 == 0) { repetir = veces + 1; } else {
                repetir = veces + 2;
            }

            for (let index = 0; index < repetir; index++) {
                conteo++;      
                // asigna el valor anterior a numero
                var valorAnterior = numero; // valor anterior
           
                if (conteo==2) {
                    numero = numero + valorAnterior;
                    // numero= numero + ValorAnterior;  
                    conteo=0;
                }

                // mostrar la sucession de numero 
                var node = document.createElement("SPAN");
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(numero+ ' ');
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.getElementById("numeros").appendChild(node);
                // console.log(numero + ',')
            }
        });
```

```html
    <h3>Diferencia en cada multiplicacion de numeros</h3>
    <form>
        <label>Numero de veces a repetir la multiplicacion:</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' id="repetir">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="ejecutar" value="Ejecutar">
    </form>
    <p id="numeros"></p>
```

El reusltado al pedir la multiplicacion por 14 es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]